# Повторное отображение строки в результате запроса SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

### Имеется задача, сформировать отчёт по продажам за конкретный день

*(одной командой `select`):*

Структура отчёта:

- Название товара (поле `NTOV`)
- Код товара (поле `KTOV`)
- количество (итого за день)
- сумма (итого за день)

### таблицы такого вида:

справочник товаров:

```
CREATE TABLE TOV
(
    KTOV char(10) primary key,
    NTOV char(60),
    SORT char(10)
);
```

документ движения товара - заголовок:

```
CREATE TABLE DMZ
(
    DDM date,
    NDM int primary key,
    PR int
);
```

документ движения товара - строки:

```
CREATE TABLE DMS
(
    KTOV char(10),
    KOL decimal(13,2),
    CENA decimal(13,2),
    SORT char(10),
    NDM int
);
```

**Запрос, который есть на текущий момент:**

```
SELECT 
    NTOV,
    DMS.KTOV,
    (SELECT SUM(KOL) FROM DMS 
        WHERE KTOV = TOV.KTOV and (DMS.NDM = (SELECT NDM FROM DMZ 
            WHERE DDM  = '1.05.2014' and PR = 2))) AS TotalKOL,
    (SELECT SUM(CENA) FROM DMS 
        WHERE KTOV = TOV.KTOV and (DMS.NDM = (SELECT NDM FROM DMZ 
            WHERE DDM  = '1.05.2014' and PR = 2))) * KOL AS TotalCENA
FROM  DMS
    INNER JOIN DMZ ON DMZ.NDM = DMS.NDM 
    INNER JOIN TOV ON DMS.KTOV = TOV.KTOV
GROUP BY NTOV, DMS.KTOV, TOV.KTOV, DMS.KOL, DMS.NDM
HAVING DMS.NDM = (SELECT NDM FROM DMZ 
        WHERE DDM  = '1.05.2014' and PR = 2)
ORDER BY TotalCENA DESC;
```

**И его результат:**

| NTOV | KTOV | TotalKOL | TotalCENA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Пиво | 101 | 5.00 | 61.0000 |
| Пиво | 101 | 5.00 | 30.5000 |
| Чипсы | 103 | 2.00 | 17.1000 |
| Пиво | 102 | 1.00 | 11.5000 |

По факту имеем двe строки с одним `KTOV` (код товара) - 101, а должно быть по одному полю на каждый товар, при чём `TotalCENA` (цена по всем продажам товара) в первой строке считается явно неадекватно и откуда-то получается `61,0000`
Вот бьюсь над этим уже второй день и понять не могу, **что я делаю не так и как это исправить**?

Comment: А зачем тут подзапросы-то в SELECT? А если использовать их - то зачем таблицы DMZ и TOV во FROM?

Comment: без внутренних `where` считает не то, что нужно

Answer (score 0):

Видимо, группировка должна быть по

```
GROUP BY DMS.KTOV
```

Comment: по факту да, так и должно быть, но `Столбец "DMS.NDM" недопустим в предложении HAVING, поскольку он не содержится ни в агрегатной функции, ни в предложении GROUP BY.` и такое сообщение про каждый столбец

Comment: и как раз я не понимаю, как не использовать столбец в `GROUP BY`, чтобы при этом всё работало